# What is the fastest way to find if a large integer is power of ten?

Tags: math, biginteger, logarithm

I could just use division and modulus in a loop, but this is slow for really large integers. The number is stored in base two, and may be as large as 2^8192. I only need to know if it is a power of ten, so I figure there may be a shortcut (other than using a lookup table).

Comment: Idea: Count the trailing zeros, then compute 5 to the power of whatever that was and compare it to your number shifted right.

Comment: What language are you working in, and what bignum implementation are you using? That'll affect what operations are cheap and what bitwise operations are available.

Comment: 10=2*5. Why didn't I think of that? Also, I am using Java and the number is stored as a simple list of integers.

Comment: Why is using a lookup table undesirable? Aside from that, maybe try successive powers of ten and see if they equal your number? Don't know if that'd be faster or slower. (To speed this idea up, you can do a binary search on the space of valid powers of ten less than 2^8192 instead of a linear search)

Comment: I know a lookup table would work. But I don't want to store one in memory.

Comment: List of integers? Like base-10 digits or base-FFFFFFFF digits or what?

Comment: to be very specific, 0-(2^32-1) digits stored in a custom linked list data structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your number x is a power of ten then

```
x = 10^y
```

for some integer y, which means that

```
x = (2^y)(5^y)
```

So, shift the integer right until there are no more trailing zeroes (should be a very low cost operation) and count the number of digits shifted (call this k). Now check if the remaining number is 5^k. If it is, then your original number is a power of 10. Otherwise, it's not. Since 2 and 5 are both prime this will always work.

Comment: Also, I could use log_2(5)*k as a length estimate and early fail test.

Comment: Another fail fast test: `add all 
the bytes of the number, and if the sum is divisible by 5, the number 
is divisible by 5`. See http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55908.html

Comment: another fail fast test is powers of five end in binary 01 and the rest of the digits follow a repeating pattern (k mod 2^number_of_digits) that can allow for a condensed table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that `X` is your input value, and we start with the assumption.

```
X = 10 ^ Something
```

Where `Something` is an `Integer`.

So we say the following:

```
log10(X) = Something.
```

So if `X` is a power of `10`, then `Something` will be an `Integer`.

**Example**

```
int x = 10000;
double test = Math.log10(x);

if(test == ((int)test))
    System.out.println("Is a power of 10");
```

Comment: This depends on a fast, ultra-high-precision implementation of the base 10 logarithm for arbitrary-precision integers. I don't think most logarithm implementations have enough precision to detect that 10^100+1 isn't a power of 10. Even if you had such a library, I doubt it would be faster than the divide/modulus loop.

Comment: Hmm.. It's a good point. But perhaps if we implement this using the `BigDecimal` class, we can take advantage of the infinite precision?

Comment: Also, you have a mistake in your first equation, it should be X = 10 ^ Something